# python2 to python3 differences with byte additions and sending to serial port

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

Currently, we are building a robot with a raspberry pi and the AX-12 dynamixel Servo's. We found a python2 library we a currently porting to python3, we pinpointed the problem in a specific method that gives an error in python3.

The Python 2 version actually works like a charm

```
AX_GOAL_LENGTH = 5
AX_WRITE_DATA = 3
AX_GOAL_POSITION_L = 30
AX_START = 255
AX_REG_WRITE = 4

def move(self, id, position):
    self.direction(Ax12.RPI_DIRECTION_TX)
    Ax12.port.flushInput()
    p = [position&0xff, position>>8]
    checksum = (~(id + Ax12.AX_GOAL_LENGTH + Ax12.AX_WRITE_DATA + Ax12.AX_GOAL_POSITION_L + p[0] + p[1]))&0xff
    outData = chr(Ax12.AX_START)
    outData += chr(Ax12.AX_START)
    outData += chr(id)
    outData += chr(Ax12.AX_GOAL_LENGTH)
    outData += chr(Ax12.AX_WRITE_DATA)
    outData += chr(Ax12.AX_GOAL_POSITION_L)
    outData += chr(p[0])
    outData += chr(p[1])
    outData += chr(checksum)
    Ax12.port.write(outData)
```

What we have tried is adjust this variable:

```
Ax12.port.write(bytes(outData,'utf-8'))
```

Now the script runs, sadly the Servo won't work anymore.

We also tried to place the bytes in a byte array

```
result = bytes([Ax12.AX_START, Ax12.AX_START, 
                Ax12.AX_GOAL_LENGTH,Ax12.AX_REG_WRITE,
                Ax12.AX_GOAL_POSITION_L, p[0], p[1], checksum
])
Ax12.port.write(result)
```

The script runs but the servo won't run.

My believe is that the operations done to outData is different in python3 then in python2. I can't find out what should be adjusted or different.

Anybody sees what I am currently doing wrong?

Comment: Your `bytes` version is missing the `id` value, and you are sending `AX_REG_WRITE` instead of `AX_WRITE_DATA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bytes are **not** UTF-8 data; for any of your `chr()` values you create outside the range 0 - 127, encoding to UTF-8 produces *two* bytes.

You were creating Unicode codepoints from integer values; these create Latin-1 codepoints if you limited those to integers between 0 and 255; in principle you could encode to `'latin1'` to get the bytes again, but it is much easier to just create bytes in the first place.

In Python 3, use the `bytes` type, created from a list of integers:

```
def move(self, id, position):
    self.direction(Ax12.RPI_DIRECTION_TX)
    Ax12.port.flushInput()
    p = [, position>>8]
    checksum = (~(id + Ax12.AX_GOAL_LENGTH + Ax12.AX_WRITE_DATA + Ax12.AX_GOAL_POSITION_L + p[0] + p[1]))&0xff
    outData = bytes([
        Ax12.AX_START, Ax12.AX_START, id,
        Ax12.AX_GOAL_LENGTH, Ax12.AX_WRITE_DATA,
        Ax12.AX_GOAL_POSITION_L, p[0], p[1], checksum])
    Ax12.port.write(outData)
```

Your own attempt did not include the `id` value and you used `AX_REG_WRITE` rather than `AX_WRITE_DATA`.

You could also use a [`bytearray()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray), which would let you append additional bytes; you could use that to calculate the checksum by referencing the bytes produced so far, avoiding having to repeat yourself (a common source of errors):

```
def move(self, id, position):
    self.direction(Ax12.RPI_DIRECTION_TX)
    Ax12.port.flushInput()
    outData = bytearray([
        Ax12.AX_START, Ax12.AX_START, id,
        Ax12.AX_GOAL_LENGTH, Ax12.AX_WRITE_DATA,
        Ax12.AX_GOAL_POSITION_L, position & 0xff, position >> 8])
    checksum = ~sum(outData[2:]) & 0xff
    outData.append(checksum)
    Ax12.port.write(outData)
```

You could use concatenation too of course (`outData = bytes([...])`, `outData += bytes([checksum])`) but `bytearray` is also available in Python 2, so the above version is compatible with both major Python versions.