# How to use RFID module MFRC522-UART serial on python 3? (encoding/decoding issue)

Tags: python-3.x, uart, rfid

I am trying to use a modified MFRC522 module on UART, but I am stuck finding the correct formatting for serial read/write in python 3.

There is a [library](https://github.com/mfdogalindo/MFRC522-UART) for python 2 which works for me:

The readme on that link also describes the modification to the module.

I'm having trouble getting the `.self.ser.write` and `.self.ser.read` in functions `writeRegister` and `readRegister` to work in python 3. These get string inputs, which I now understand is fine for python 2, but must be converted to bytes for python 3.

```
def writeRegister(self, addr, val, size=None):
    if size is None:
      count = 0
      while True:
        self.ser.flushInput()
        self.ser.write(chr(addr&0x7F))
        self.ser.write(chr(val))
        tmp = ord(self.ser.read(1))   
        if(tmp == addr):      
          return True
        count+=1
        if(count > 10):
          print ("Error de escritura en: "+ hex(addr))
          return False  
    else:       
      self.ser.flushInput()
      for txBytes in range (0, size):
        self.ser.write(chr(addr&0x7F))
        tmp = ord(self.ser.read(1))
        if(tmp == addr):
          self.ser.write(chr(val[txBytes]))
        else:
          print ("Error de escritura en bloque")
          return False

      return True    

  def readRegister(self, addr):
    self.ser.flushInput()
    self.ser.write(chr(addr|0x80))
    val = self.ser.read(1)
    return ord(val)
```

I suspected it's a matter of correctly applying `.encode('utf-8')` or similar, but I can't find a working solution. If I try

```
chr(0x80).encode('utf-8')
```

I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Maybe I am going down the wrong path with that.
I'll try `bytes`:

```
bytes(chr(0x80), 'utf-8')
```

Gives 2 bytes in this case (>128 i guess):

```
b'\xc2\x80'
```

Maybe this is getting closer, but I get stuck on how to read back and decode. I don't know how or if to modify the `ord` parts. So I can't seem to get the response from the mfrc522.

Does anyone have any suggestions? 
Anybody successfully used this mfrc522 UART on python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to use `char` in either Python 2.x or 3.x, you can just write bytes to the port:
   `self.ser.write(bytes[addr&0x7F])`

For the reading function just drop the `ord()` from the return sentence, it's not needed for Python 3.x.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118807/11476836) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

That did it, thanks!
Here are the corrected functions:

```
  def writeRegister(self, addr, val, size=None):
    if size is None:
      count = 0
      while True:
        self.ser.flushInput()
        self.ser.write(bytes([addr&0x7F]))
        self.ser.write(bytes([val]))
        tmp = int.from_bytes(self.ser.read(1), "big")
        if(tmp == addr):
          return True
        count+=1
        if(count > 10):
          print ("Write error at: "+ hex(addr))
          return False  
    else:       
      self.ser.flushInput()
      if(tmp == addr):
          self.ser.write(bytes([val]))
      else:
          print ("Block write error")
          return False
      return True    

  def readRegister(self, addr):
    self.ser.flushInput()
    self.ser.write(bytes([addr|0x80]))
    val = self.ser.read(1)
    return int.from_bytes(val, "big")
```